# Auto-generated C++ file in the Pre-build not included in the compilation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a custom parser that generate C++ files and add them into a project. What I would like to do is call this parser before building my project and compile the new generated files in the same build. I use VS2010. I tried to call the parser in the PreBuild, the generated files are correctly added in the project (I can see them in the IDE) but they are not compiled. Like if the project doesn’t know that it have new files in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but do not fully know, if files added to the project during the PreBuild phase are actually included in the compilation.  I believe that the files included is calculated before the PreBuild phase is run.

One way to work around this though is to add an empty file into the project and include it in the compilation.  Have your prebuild phase overwrite this file and the postbuild phase re-initialize it to nothing.  That should fix this issue.

Comment: You have a point. It doesn't seem possible to include the file in the compilation during the PreBuild step.

Answer (score 0):

If the generated files are named .cpp they should be compiled. Otherwise you might need to specify that they should be compiled as c++ files, somehow.

If your generated files are created from some other file which you edit, you can set up a custom compile step on the "input" files for your generator. That helps with re-building files.

Answer (score 0):

Autogenerated files aren't auto-added to the project and therefore aren't compiled. You see them in the IDE because they lie in the same folder(s) as your project files.

The only snag with overwriting an existing project file with new, auto-generated contents is that, if you use a source control system, those files will be read-only. Overwriting them during an auto-generation phase might upset your source control process.

You could try this:

```
MyProject/
    MyWrapperFile.cpp <-- official project file
```

MyWrapperFile.cpp contents

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "_AutoGenFile1.cpp"
#include "_AutoGenFile2.cpp"
// etc.
```